# How to enter chroot on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automation, chroot, chromium-os

Hi i am trying to automate the process of sync and build chromium builds on a Jenkins server 
http://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/quick-start-guide

```
./chromite/bin/cros_sdk --enter
```

i am trying to run something like this ,the desired output is expected to be a chroot prompt with a changed home directory, I have a Jenkins slave and when i do these steps manually, i am able to enter chroot without any issues and it provides me with the changed home directory and the path shows up where i need it to be for the next step ,

But when i roll this into a Jenkins Execute Shell on the same machine and same credentials, it is not able enter chroot,

```
./chromite/bin/cros_sdk --enter --log-level=debug
15:59:05: DEBUG: Cache dir lookup.
15:59:05: DEBUG: Configured cache_dir to '/media/1TB/home/qcaswnbu/jenkins1/workspace/Brillo_trial/.cache'
```

This is what i get in Jenkins

Manually though

```
./chromite/bin/cros_sdk --enter --log-level=debug
17:27:05: DEBUG: Cache dir lookup.
17:27:05: DEBUG: Configured cache_dir to '/media/1TB/home/qcaswnbu/jenkins1/workspace/Brillo_trial/.cache'
17:27:05: DEBUG: Configured cache_dir to '/media/1TB/home/qcaswnbu/jenkins1/workspace/Brillo_trial/.cache'
```

i get an extra line with the same message , could there be a chance its quitting half way through when it is initiated from Jenkins job ?

any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Prem

Answer (score 1):

when you run `cros_sdk` by itself, it expects an interactive prompt.  i imagine Jenkins has no terminal attached (by design) which means trying to use it that way doesn't make much sense.

we've designed the tool so it can easily be scripted.  if you have some command you want to run inside of the chroot, simply pass it as an argument:

```
$ cros_sdk -- ls /
bin  build  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64 ....
```

i think that should get you everything you need.